# data_mapper, attr_accessor, & serialization only serializing properties not attr_accessor attributes

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper, attr-accessor

I'm using data_mapper/sinatra and trying to create some attributes with attr_accessor.  The following example code:

```
require 'json'
class Person
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,          Serial
  property :first_name,  String
  attr_accessor  :last_name
end

ps = Person.new
ps.first_name = "Mike"
ps.last_name = "Smith"
p ps.to_json
```

produces this output:

```
"{\"id\":null,\"first_name\":\"Mike\"}"
```

Obviously I would like for it to give me both the first and last name attributes.  Any ideas on how to get this to work in the way one would expect so that my json has all of the attributes?

Also, feel free to also explain why my expectation (that I'd get all of the attributes) is incorrect.  I'm guessing some internal list of attributes isn't getting the attr_accessor instance variables added to it or something.  But even so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Matt I did some digging and found the :method param for dm-serializer's to_json method. Their to_json method was pretty decent and was basically just a wrapper for an as_json helper method so I overwrote it by just adding a few lines:

```
  if options[:include_attributes]
    options[:methods] = [] if options[:methods].nil?
    options[:methods].concat(model.attributes).uniq!
  end
```

The completed method override looks like:

```
module DataMapper
  module Serializer

    def to_json(*args)
      options = args.first
      options = {} unless options.kind_of?(Hash)

      if options[:include_attributes]
        options[:methods] = [] if options[:methods].nil?
        options[:methods].concat(model.attributes).uniq!
      end

      result = as_json(options)

      # default to making JSON
      if options.fetch(:to_json, true)
        MultiJson.dump(result)
      else
        result
      end
    end

  end
end
```

This works along with an attributes method I added to a base module I use with my models.  The relevant section is below:

```
module Base

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def attr_accessor(*vars)
      @attributes ||= []
      @attributes.concat vars
      super(*vars)
    end

    def attributes
      @attributes || []
    end
  end

  def attributes
    self.class.attributes
  end

end
```

now my original example:

```
require 'json'
class Person
  include DataMapper::Resource
  include Base

  property :id,          Serial
  property :first_name,  String
  attr_accessor  :last_name
end

ps = Person.new
ps.first_name = "Mike"
ps.last_name = "Smith"
p ps.to_json :include_attributes => true
```

Works as expected, with the new option parameter.

What I could have done to selectively get the attributes I wanted without having to do the extra work was to just pass the attribute names into the :methods param.

```
p ps.to_json :methods => [:last_name]
```

Or, since I already had my `Base` class:

```
p ps.to_json :methods => Person.attributes
```

Now I just need to figure out how I want to support collections.

Answer (score 2):

Datamapper has it’s own serialization library, [`dm-serializer`](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer), that provides a `to_json` method for any Datamapper resource. If you require Datamapper with `require 'data_mapper'` in your code, you are using the [`data_mapper` meta-gem](https://github.com/datamapper/data_mapper) that [requires dm-serializer as part of it’s set up](https://github.com/datamapper/data_mapper/blob/4d565b51d46f736b7092598a5a3d8a6d5361f572/lib/data_mapper.rb#L7).

The `to_json` method provided by `dm-serializer` only serializes the Datamapper properties of your object (i.e. those you’ve specified with `property`) and not the “normal” properties (that you’ve defined with `attr_accessor`). This is why you get `id` and `first_name` but not `last_name`.

In order to avoid using `dm-serializer` you need to explicitly require those libraries you need, rather than rely on `data_mapper`. You will need at least `dm-core` and maybe others.

The “normal” `json` library doesn’t include any attributes in the default `to_json` call on an object, it just uses the objects `to_s` method. So in this case, if you replace `require 'data_mapper'` with `require 'dm-core'`, you will get something like `"\"#<Person:0x000001013a0320>\""`.

To create json representations of your own objects you need to create your own `to_json` method. A simple example would be to just hard code the attributes you want in the json:

```
def to_json
  {:id => id, :first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name}.to_json
end
```

You could create a method that looks at the attributes and properties of the object and create the appropriate json from that instead of hardcoding them this way.

Note that if you create your own `to_json` method you could still call `require 'data_mapper'`, your `to_json` will replace the one provided by `dm-serializer`. In fact `dm-serializer` also adds an [`as_json` method](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer/blob/v1.2.0/lib/dm-serializer/to_json.rb#L18) that you could use to create the combined `to_json` method, e.g.:

```
def to_json
  as_json.merge({:last_name => last_name}).to_json
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of dm-serializer.  I spelunked the code a bit and realized that the :methods param, which the documentation says is there to include related relationships, can also be used to include attributes.  I then overrode dm-serializer's to_json method and added an :include_attributes => true option param.  I'll be posting some code to explain better.

Comment: @umassthrower oh yeah, I didn’t notice the `methods` option. You could do `def to_json; super :methods => :last_name; end` in your `Person` class to get the same result.